# Interpolating from a pandas DataFrame or Series to a new DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation

Let's say I have an hourly series in pandas, fine to assume the source is regular but it is gappy. If I want to interpolate it to 15min, the pandas API provides `resample(15min).interpolate('cubic')`. It interpolates to the new times and provides some control over the limits of interpolation. The spline is helping to refine the series as well as fill small gaps. To be concrete:

```
tndx = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01",end="2019-01-10",freq="H")    
tnum = np.arange(0.,len(tndx))
signal = np.cos(tnum*2.*np.pi/24.)

signal[80:85] = np.nan   # too wide a gap
signal[160:168:2] = np.nan   # these can be interpolated

df = pd.DataFrame({"signal":signal},index=tndx)    
df1= df.resample('15min').interpolate('cubic',limit=9)
```

Now let's say I have an irregular datetime index. In the example below, the first time is a regular time point, the second is in the big gap and the last is in the interspersed brief gaps.

```
tndx2 = pd.DatetimeIndex('2019-01-04 00:00','2019-01-04 10:17','2019-01-07 16:00')
```

How do I interpolate to from the original series (hourly) to this irregular series of times?

Is the only option to build a series that includes the original data and the destination data? How would I do this? What is the most economical way to achieve the goals of interpolating to an independent irregular index and imposing a gap limit?

Comment: You could `resample` the original data to `1s`, then use `reindex`, or index slice the interpolated data.

Comment: Thanks. I see this could work, and if you knew the "least common denominator" (say 1 minute here rather than 1 second) it might do the job .But it is heavy for my context, particularly if the interpolators themselves are expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example solution within the pandas interpolate API, which doesn't seem to have a way of using abscissa and values from the source series to interpolate to new times provided by the destination index, as separate data structure. This method solves this by tacking the destination to the source. The method makes use of the `limit` argument of `df.interpolate` and it can use any interpolation algorithm from that API but it isn't perfect because the limit is in terms of the number of values and if there are a lot of destination points in a patch of NaNs those get counted as well.

```
tndx = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01",end="2019-01-10",freq="H")    
tnum = np.arange(0.,len(tndx))
signal = np.cos(tnum*2.*np.pi/24.)

signal[80:85] = np.nan
signal[160:168:2] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({"signal":signal},index=tndx)

# Express the destination times as a dataframe and append to the source
tndx2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-04 00:00','2019-01-04 10:17','2019-01-07 16:00'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {"signal": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]} , index = tndx2)
big_df = df.append(df2,sort=True)  

# At this point there are duplicates with NaN values at the bottom of the DataFrame
# representing the destination points. If these are surrounded by lots of NaNs in the source frame
# and we want the limit argument to work in the call to interpolate, the frame has to be sorted and duplicates removed.     
big_df = big_df.loc[~big_df.index.duplicated(keep='first')].sort_index(axis=0,level=0)

# Extract at destination locations
interpolated = big_df.interpolate(method='cubic',limit=3).loc[tndx2]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of irregular timestamps, first you set datetime as index and then you can use `interpolate` method to `index` `df1= df.resample('15min').interpolate('index')`

You can find more information here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: I am trying to interpolate from a source series to a destination series or index (my bad for not saying this more clearly). Unless you are implying a lot of extra steps like combining the source and destination I don't see you are addressing my case. Also, on a more subtle level I don't know what the algorithm underlying  `interpolate('index')` is -- I assume linear?